# Limit the applicability of a Java interface

Tags: java

Is it possible to limit the applicability of a Java interface? In other words, if I have a class A, and a Java interface I: Is it possible to enforce, that an instance of I is also an instance of A?

Or, again in other words: If I have something like

```java
public class B implements I {
}
```

I want the compiler to throw an error, if B is **not** a subclass of A.

`A` is an upstream class that I cannot modify. Some subclasses of `A` (my own) would be implementing `I`, but others would not.

My interface is going to contain a lot of methods like:

```java
public default void foo() { 
    ((A) this).doSomething(...); 
}
```

My intention is to ensure that the cast to `A` is guaranteed to work.

Comment: No. But if `A` were an interface, then `I` could extend `A`, meaning every `B` is necessarily an `A`.

Comment: You can create a sealed interface.

Comment: @daniu It was my first thought, but it's not the same. Sealed enumerates what can implement the interface. He doesn't want to enumerate it. He just wants a kind of constraint.

Comment: I understood the question to mean that some subclasses of `A` may implement `I` while others do not, but `A` does not generally implement `I`. @user1774051 can you clarify?

Comment: Are you going to use your type in generics?

Comment: Restricting implementation to a specific base class implies that `I` is not really an interface because you care about the actual implementation rather than just available behavior. Have you considered using an abstract class rather than an interface?

Answer (score 8):

If you are on java 17+, you can use [sealed interfaces/classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html#GUID-0C709461-CC33-419A-82BF-61461336E65F). Since `A` is not modifiable, you would need a parent class of your own. Permit only `BaseForI` (or other suitable name) to implement `I`.

When you seal an interface (or class), with keyword `sealed`, you also declare allowed inheritors, with `permits`:

```
public sealed interface I permits BaseForI {

  default void foo() {
    ((BaseForI) this).doSomething();
  }
}
```

The allowed inheritor (class or another interface) then must be declared either:

1. `final` - you can't extend it (applicable only for a class).
2. `non-sealed` - open for extension.
3. `sealed` - inheritor can be sealed as well, the same rules apply.

For your case you want the parent to be non-sealed:

```
public non-sealed class BaseForI extends A implements I {
}
```

The compiler won't allow implementors of `I`, different from `BaseForI`, which is an `A`.

```
public class B implements I {
}
```

The example above results in a compilation error - `'B' is not allowed in the sealed hierarchy`. `B` extending from `BaseForI` on the other hand is allowed, since the base is `non-sealed`.

```
public class B extends BaseForI {
}
```

But there is a big **but** - this is a good example, why you should favour composition over inheritance. A good read on the topic - [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance). Provide a base implementation for `I`, which depends on `A` to do the job.

```
public abstract class CompositionClass implements I {

  private final A a;

  @Override
  public void foo() {
    this.a.doSomething();
  }
}
```

No need to cast and less complicated. You can still seal `I` to allow a path of extension only through `CompositionClass`.

Comment: You just end up with an interface that's not implementable by anything except `A`. So you might as well ditch `I` and just use `A` everywhere.

Comment: @Michael Well, this is exactly what the **question wants** - `I want the compiler to throw an error, if B is not a subclass of A.`

Comment: It is not clear from the question of `A` implements `I` by itself. If it does, this is the solution.

Comment: OP clarified in the comments that they cannot modify `A` to implement `I`, so this does not work for his specific usecase.

Comment: @julaine It works with a base class implementing `I`, I updated the answer to address the requirement of `A` being non modifiable. But this is really just a good exercise on using sealed, the correct solution is for OP to favour composition over inheritance as it simplifies quite a bit everything, which I also addressed as a possible solution.

Comment: @Chaosfire nice literal solution, I upvoted. Though I think this makes `I` essentially useless. Every instance of `I` is also an instance of `BaseForI`. Might as well put the methods directly in `BaseForI` and forget about `I`. default methods become concrete, and non-default-methods become abstract.

Comment: @julaine I also don't see the point of `I`, but as a personal preference I always use interfaces even in those cases, because it makes it explicit what is the intended public API.

Answer (score 2):

So your restrictions are:

- `A` can not be modified and does not implement `I`
- There are other subclasses of `A` that you can not modify.
- You want to make (several) subclasses of `A` that implement `I`
- `I` will have default methods that can only work on objects of type `A`

I believe this is an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your goal is to make subclasses of `A` and they should share functionality. You have two options:

(1) Make a subclass of `A` called `Asub` and add your `I`-functionality to `Asub`. Then, your class `B` can be declared as `class B extends Asub`.

(2) Avoid deeply nested class hierarchies and [Don't pay inheritance tax](https://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpp20/inheritance-tax.pdf). Write your extra-functionality as static methods or methods of some service-class. Your subclasses of `A` can use them by putting `this` into your own functions.

Option (1) is very close to the model you have in mind already. Think about it: If you want to make classes that are subtypes of `I` and `A` and forbid the situation that something could be an `I` but not an `A`, that means you want `I` to be a subset of `A`. Make this relation explicit by ditching the idea of the interface `I` and use a class, `Asub` instead.